# Logback doesn't print after SpringApplication.run

Tags: java, spring, logback

Somehow Logback is not printing but System.out.println is, after SpringApplication.run. I am trying to print out the beans that are loaded up in the context. Sure I can do that with System.out. But I would like to do that with logbook. Can anyone explain what I am missing in the code below?

```
import java.util.Arrays;    

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;    

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {    

  final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApplication.class);    

  public static void main(String[] args) {    

    // This works fine. I am using logback behind the slf4j api. 
    logger.debug("Hello world from Spring Boot.");    

    ApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(
        MyApplication.class, args);   

    // The system.out works all right. The debug does not. Why?
    logger.debug("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");
    System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");   

    String[] beanNames = appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    Arrays.sort(beanNames);
    for (String beanName : beanNames) {
      System.out.println(beanName);
    }
  }
}
```

**/pom.xml**

```
<groupId>fun.and.games</groupId>
<artifactId>learnspringboot</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <!-- mvn -e clean install exec:java -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>fun.and.games.MyApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Configure the project to use java 8 version. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <!-- Disable annotation processing for ourselves. -->
                <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- mvn -e clean install spring-boot:run -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**src/main/resources/application.properties**

```
logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you didn't include a SLF4J implementation in your dependencies, but you are using SLF4J simple logger, which doesn't do anything. Add a SLF4J-log4j logger or slf4j-logback, and it should work.

Comment: The "Hello world from Spring Boot." prints fine. So, it should not be the case of missing logback. I think. Did you have time to try running the code? This public gist has all the code. https://gist.github.com/kaunjovi/b336886f319533f443cfbac1ec081abe

Comment: plz show your pom or gradle.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Did you ever solve it, @kaunjovi?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add dependency for Logback in pom.xml as spring boot provides SLF4J and Logback dependencies. Spring Boot provides a default configuration for Logback in configuration file and INFO messages can be printed by default in your application. If you want to get the DEBUG messages in the log then you have to configure that in application.properties file. Add logging.level.your package=DEBUG in property file. For example your package is "com.my.app" then use

```
logging.level.com.my.app=DEBUG
```

And Spring web DEBUG log can be enabled like

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

Please check details for logging levels at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Comment: I created a ** /src/main/resources/application.properties**. In that I have added a single line **logging.level.root=DEBUG**. But no luck. By the way, I did not need to add logback as an explicit dependency. Thanks for that.

Comment: Try clean build your project. I tested your java class and pom.xml and I am getting the debug logs printed.